# Image of continuous $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

[Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Image_of_Closed_Real_Interval_is_Bounded) is a proof of the theorem in title I'm working through.

This is a proof by contradiction, first assuming that it isn't bounded. Here I got the result that there is a sequence $\langle x_n \rangle \subseteq [a,b]$ such that $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}, \exists n$ with $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$.

The second result I got is that $\langle x_n \rangle$ has a subsequence $\langle x_{n_r}\rangle$ converging to a $\xi \in [a,b]$, which in turn implies $\displaystyle \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_r})=f(\xi)$.

The site I linked to says that these two results are contradictory, which I can't see - where is the logical contradiction between these two?

Comment: If $|f(x_n)|$ goes to infinity and $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(\xi)$ then $f(\xi)=|\infty|$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there is a sequence $\langle x_n \rangle \subseteq [a\,..b]$ such that $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}:\exists f(x_n):|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$

For simplicity, let's make a small, subtle change and let $x_n$ instead be a sequence such that $|f(x_n)|$ diverges to infinity (it's a subsequence of the one in the highlighted text).  In other words, $x_n$ is a sequence such that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|f(x_n)| > \varepsilon$ for *all* sufficiently large $n$.

$\large{ \dagger}$ Next, let's set $\varepsilon >> |f(\xi)|$.  The above means that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n \geq N$, we must have $f(x_n) > \varepsilon$.

> $\langle x_n \rangle$ has a subsequence $\langle x_{n_r}\rangle$ converging to a $\xi \in [a\,..b]$, which in turn implies $\displaystyle \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_r})=f(\xi)$.

Yes, this is a consequence of [Bolzano-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).  Now taking everything above together, this is the contradiction:

If $x_{n_r}$ converges to $\xi$, this means an infinite number of terms in $x_n$ must be "close" to $\xi$, which means we must have an infinite number of evaluations $f(x_{n})$ "close" to $f(\xi)$.  However, due to $\large{\dagger}$ above, only a finite number of terms can be "close" to $f(\xi)$ since $f(x_n) >> f(\xi)$ for all $n \geq N$.

---

There are some other methods of tackling this proof as well that are worth mentioning:

**Alternative Method $1$**:  One can prove that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.  Recall that [uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Definition_for_functions_on_metric_spaces) means, given an $\varepsilon > 0$ the same $\delta$ works at every $x$ in the domain.  Therefore, if we compute $\displaystyle n = \Bigg\lceil \frac{|b-a|}{\delta} \Bigg\rceil$, then the "diameter" of $f([a,b])$ cannot be larger than $\varepsilon \cdot n$.

**Alternative Method $2$**:  One can prove that [the continuous image of a compact set is itself compact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact).  Since $[a,b]$ is compact, then so too is $f([a,b])$.  What are the [necessary and sufficient conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) for a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be compact?

Comment: Your first conclusion is wrong… you just have divergence of a subsequence of $x_n$ to $\infty$

Comment: Good catch @Gono.  Subtle, and I wasn't reading carefully enough.  I made note of this in an edit; working with that divergent subsequence is the easiest way to the conclusion, IMO.

Comment: @KajHansen "For simplicity, let's make a small, subtle change and let $x_n$ instead be a sequence such that $f(x_n)$ diverges to infinity (it's a subsequence of the one in the highlighted text). In other words, $x_n$ is a sequence such that, for any $ε>0$, we have $f(x_n)>ε$ for all sufficiently large $n$." How to make such a change - i.e. prove that $\forall \epsilon:\exists n:|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$ implies $\forall \epsilon:\exists N:\forall n>N:|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$?

Comment: @asdasdfsss, those two things in your last sentence don't imply each other (assuming I'm interpreting notation correctly).  That's exactly the thing I want to fix.  Given how $a_n$ was originally defined, we can always find a $k$ for which $|f(a_k)| > \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon$.  Now, for example, we can let $\varepsilon_m = m$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$.  Let $a_{n_m}$ be a subsequence of points in $a_n$ such that $|f(a_{n_m})| > \varepsilon_m = m$, which is possible to do from the above.

Comment: What I'm saying is to redefine the sequence $a_n$ to be this subsequence $a_{n_m}$, which diverges to infinity, because doing so makes the contradiction easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, technically. 
The statement is ofc true, you just need to change notation a bit to make it clear… and a little bit more work to do.

You get the existence of a sequence $\langle x_n \rangle \subseteq [a\,..b]$ with $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}:\exists f(x_n):|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$

So you can conclude there exists a subsequence $\langle x_{n_r} \rangle$ which diverges to $+\infty$ monotonously!

For this subsequence $\langle x_{n_r} \rangle\subseteq [a\,..b]$ you know there exists a subsubsequence $\langle x_{n_{r_q}} \rangle$ converging to $\xi$… and then you have your contradiction

Answer (score 1):

The quoted proof uses a much stronger fact about the sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$, namely that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n)|=\infty
$$
In particular, for every subsequence,
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}|f(x_{n_r})|=\infty
$$
which contradicts
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}f(x_{n_r})=f(\xi)
$$

The existence of the sequence can be proved as follows: since $f$ is unbounded, for every $n$ there exists $x_n$ with $|f(x_n)|>n$.

---

A different strategy not using Bolzano-Weierstraß is by bisection. Set $a_0=a$ and $b_0=b$. Since $f$ is unbounded, it will be either in $[a_0..(a_0+b_0)/2]$ or in $[(a_0+b_0)/2..b_0]$ (or both). Choose the half-interval $[a_1..b_1]$ where $f$ is unbounded.

Such a construction can be repeated on $[a_1..b_1]$ and so on, leading to a nested family of intervals $[a_n..b_n]$, of width $(b-a)/2^n$, over each of which $f$ is unbounded.

It's easy to see that $\sup_n a_n=\inf_n b_n$, call this point $c$. Since $f$ is continuous at $c$, it is bounded in an interval $(c-\delta..c+\delta)\cap[a..b]$, for some $\delta>0$.

Take $n$ such that $(b-a)/2^n<\delta$ and you have a contradiction.

Comment: How do we know that for every subsequence the limit is infinite? I found a proof that has this property for a sequence converging to $l \in \mathbb R$, but our sequence doesn't converge to any $l$.

Comment: @asdasdfsss Prove it: it's just applying the definitions.